# Issue on deploying phonegap build directly to windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-build

Iam doing a phonegap project now, i have deployed my app to many android devices, all works fine. Started on **windows phone** & i found [**here**](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/windows_phone_8_compatibility_with_phonegap_build) **phonegap apps cant deploy directly to windows phone**.
*I want to know; whether the steps given below (Steps for unlocking windows phone) will make my build (.xap file from phonegap build) runnable on windows os device?*

- Install the Windows Phone 8 SDK if you do not have it on the system. This is required for all developers.
- Register for a Windows Phone developer account. If you are a DreamSpark member, you can register for free.
- After the SDK is installed on the system, search for the Windows Phone Developer Registration program from the start screen.
- Connect your phone to the computer. The program should detect the device immediately. Hit the Register button when it is clickable.
- A log-in window will show up on screen. Please fill in your developer account information in the appropriate field, and then hit Sign in. The device registration process will start once you are signed in. If you are successful, you will receive the following message: Congratulations! You have successfully unlocked your Windows Phone.
- Each developer account can unlock up to three devices. If you want to delete a device from the account, log in to the developer Dashboard, choose Account -> Phones, and then delete the device from there.

Please help me.

Comment: The thread you link to relates to using phonegap build and implies there is an issue with apps built there. But if you're installing the SDK on your machine, you can build with that.

Comment: @MattLacey: After registering as windows phone developer and unlocking my windows phone- is it possible to make build using phonegap build service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

The Development team said they are looking into it and expecting to have it ready Q3 - Q4 this year.

Here's a link to the feature request(https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/118)

Ismael

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now supported. We can create `.xap` file with Phonegap online build itself.  It is beta so there are some limitations.

[Check here](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/10/18/2013-10-18-phonegap-build-support-for-windows-phone-8/)